# How to assign values to checkbox in html when check and uncheck?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a html checkbox in my html form. Now, i want to assign 1 when it is checked and assign 0 when it is unchecked. So, how can i do that with jquery or java Script?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  <!--
  function greeter() {
      alert(document.getElementById(vehicleChkBox).value);
  }
  $('#vehicleChkBox').change(function(){
       if($(this).attr('checked')){
            $(this).val(1);
       }else{
            $(this).val(0);
       }
  });
  </script>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" id="vehicleChkBox" value="FALSE" />
      <input type="submit" onsubmit="greeter()">
    </form>
  </body>
```

I tried with this. but, does not work.

Comment: Please post ur code and what you have tried so far!

Comment: Assign to value of checkbox.

Answer (score 4):

JS:

```
var checkbox = document.querySelector("input[type='checkbox']");
  checkbox.addEventListener("change",function(){
     this.value = this.checked ? 1 : 0;
  });
```

jQuery:

```
$(":checkbox").change(function(){
     $(this).val($(this).is(":checked") ? 1 : 0);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use JQuery for this with `change` event:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#vehicleChkBox').on('change', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    this.value = this.checked ? 1 : 0;
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" id="vehicleChkBox" value="0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to put its value as 1. This way when it is checked it will return 1 and when it is not checked it will return nothing so that way you can do a check and assign zero.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="my_checkbox" value="1" />
```

Comment: Where does the dynamic value come from??

Comment: when we check assign 1 and uncheck assign 0.

Comment: That is what this does. I think you need to get more familiar with how forms work.

Comment: is it changing when we check and uncheck?

Answer (score 0):

I am using this and this is working absolutely fine:

```
$("#checkkBoxId").attr("checked") ? alert("Checked") : alert("Unchecked");
```

Note: If the checkbox is checked it will return true otherwise undefined, so better check for the "TRUE" value.

OR

```
if(!$("#checkkBoxId").is(':checked') ){
 $(this).val('1');
}
else
$(this).val('0');
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work fine for setting value

```
   $("#checkkBoxId").prop("checked") ? ($("#checkkBoxId").val(1)) :    ($("#checkkBoxId").val(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script> 
   $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#vehicleChkBox').click(function(){
             if($(this).is(':checked'))
             {              
                  $(this).val('1');
             }
             else
             {
                 $(this).val('0');
             }
         });
    });
</script>
```